# Python 3.5 Tkinter "unstable" warning in IDLE

Tags: python, tkinter, activetcl, python-install

I just installed Python 3.5 from the python website. After seeing this error message on IDLE :

```
  WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
 Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
```

I installed Active tcl. Yet I still get the same error when I open IDLE.
How do I go about correcting this ?

Comment: The current TCL version is 8.6. It has many changes like the menubutton is now obsolete.

Comment: @DhruvSomani: where did you read that the menubutton is obsolete?